# Progress spinner inside textview or autocompletetextview

Tags: android

I would like to create autocompletetextview with loading spinner inside (like in bilt-in Android browser, when page is loaging).

How can I implement it?

Also is it existing drawable inside android framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could use a FrameLayout for the spinner, then add padding to get it in the right position. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)